# Graphs with various Y values and one X values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code i use to create a graph which searches for .csv {created using excel application} file in the path specified. It plots the column 'B' { Y axis } against column 'C' {X-axis}.. I want to one more column 'A' to my Y axis keeping column 'C' as the X axis.. How can i do that???

here is the code...

```
Sub Draw_Graph()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strChart As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    strPath = "C:\PortableRvR\report\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    i = 1

    Do While strFile <> ""
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, _
                Destination:=.Range("A1"))
                Parent.Name = Replace(strFile, ".csv", "")
                TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
                TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                Files(i) = .Parent.Name
                i = i + 1
            End With
        End With
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    numOfFiles = i - 1
    chartName = "Chart 1"

    For j = 1 To numOfFiles
        strFile = Files(j)
        Sheets(strFile).Select
        Plot_y = Range("B1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Plot_x = Range("C1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        Sheets("GraphDisplay").Select
        If j = 1 Then ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Name = strFile
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).XValues = Sheets(strFile).Range("C1:C" & Plot_x)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Values = Sheets(strFile).Range("B1:B" & Plot_y)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).MarkerStyle = -4142
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Smooth = False
    Next j

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlMillions
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasDisplayUnitLabel = False
End Sub
```

Comment: did you try ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Values = Sheets(strFile).Range(**"A1:B"** & Plot_y)?

Comment: You cannot change your question when you have already accepted your answer. Please ask a new question. You may refer to this question from that question. I have rolled back the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add 2 series for every file (j and j+1 inside `for j = 1 to 2*numOfFiles step 2`) and repeat everything for j+1 series except:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Values = Sheets(strFile).Range("A1:A" & Plot_y)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j+1).Values = Sheets(strFile).Range("B1:B" & Plot_y)
```

Comment: I still get the same error, should i make any changes to these lines?                                                                          Plot_y = Range("B1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Plot_x = Range("C1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Comment: in that case try only `A1:A` in your original code - if you still get the error, there might be something wrong with your data, not with your code :))

Comment: i have no idea what the problem is, then :(

Comment: @user1270123: I can look into this if that is OK with you. :) However would it be possible to see any one csv file? Also create a graph manually from that csv file and post a screenshot on how it should look. You may use www.wikisend.com or skydrive to upload the file and then post the link here :)

Comment: @user1270123: Will have a look at it soon. I am working on another post at the moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Not for points**

I was planning to post this as a comment (*and hence do not select this as an answer. All credit to @Aprillion*) but the comment would not have formatted the code as this post would have done.

Whenever you add a series as Aprillion mentioned you have to also add one more line. I just tested this with small piece of data and it works.

```
'<~~ You have to call this everytime you add a new series
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries 
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6"
'<~~ You have to call this everytime you add a new series
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6"
```

Also since there is a huge difference between your Series 1 Data and Series 2 data (as per the snapshot), the 2nd series will be very close to X Axis.

Hope this is what you wanted?

**FOLLOWUP**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim files(1 To 20) As String
Dim numOfFiles As Integer
Dim chartName As String, shName as String

Sub Time_Graph()
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, strChart As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

    strPath = "C:\PortableRvR\report\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

    i = 1

    Do While strFile <> ""
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            shName = strFile
            ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(shName, ".csv", "")
            With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, _
                Destination:=.Range("A1"))
                .Name = Replace(strFile, ".csv", "")
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                files(i) = .Parent.Name
                i = i + 1
            End With
        End With
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    numOfFiles = i - 1
    chartName = "Chart 1"

    For j = 1 To numOfFiles
        If n = 0 Then n = j Else n = n + 2
        strFile = files(j)
        Sheets(strFile).Select
        Plot_y = Range("B1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Plot_x = Range("C1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        Sheets("GraphDisplay").Select

        If j = 1 Then ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Activate

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Name = strFile & " - Col B Values"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).XValues = "=" & strFile & "!$C$1:$C$" & Plot_x
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Values = "=" & strFile & "!$B$1:$B$" & Plot_y

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n + 1).Name = strFile & " - Col A Values"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n + 1).XValues = "=" & strFile & "!$C$1:$C$" & Plot_x
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n + 1).Values = "=" & strFile & "!$A$1:$A$" & Plot_y

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).MarkerStyle = -4142
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Smooth = False
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n + 1).MarkerStyle = -4142
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n + 1).Smooth = False
    Next j

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlMillions
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasDisplayUnitLabel = False
End Sub
```

Comment: gimme sometime. I will look at this post once i finish with the other :) Don't worry, we will get this sorted ;)

Comment: This is the csv file    http://wikisend.com/download/356916/3X3-18-149-40-d00600101-TCP-up.csv

Comment: Hope your queries are finally sorted?